# State-transition diagram for a Mealy machine

Tags: circuit-design, state-machines

I created a state-transition diagram for the Mealy machine below. but I wasn't sure if it was correct. The part that confused me was that s1 has no edges.

[image]

Comment: Aren't you missing loops on S1 to show it's outputs?

Answer (score 2):

It does have edges — the last two lines of the table — you simply haven't drawn them. They loop back to itself, just like the `0/0` edge does on the S0 state.

Comment: The goal wasn't to draw the state machine. I wanted to create the state transition diagram for it. So should I just erase the last two lines?

Comment: The "diagram" is on the left, the "table" is on the right. There is a one-to-one correspondence between edges (arrows) in the diagram and lines in the table. You either need to add two edges in the diagram or delete two lines from the table.